# Powershell run multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql, powershell, output

I am trying to run multiple SQL queries and get the result in some txt/csv file, but I am getting an error that I am not able to fix. Any advice?

```
$dbServer = "dbserver"
$extractFile = "C:\test\" + $timer + ".csv"
$Database = "b
$User = "Admin"
$Pass = "psswd"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dbServer;Database=$db;uid=$User;password=$Pass;"
$SQLConnection.Open()
$SQLCommand = $SQLConnection.CreateCommand()
$SQLCommand.CommandText = 
"select count(*) 'Nombre de Address mail' FROM dbo.UsersParticipations"
"select count(*) 'Nombre de Transactions' FROM dbo.Transactions;"
$readAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$readSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$readAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand
$readAdapter.Fill($readSet) |out-null
$SQLConnection.Close()
    Foreach ($row in $readSet.Tables[0].rows) {
   Write-Output "Adress"
   Write-Output "$($row.size)  $($row.job)"
}
Foreach ($row in $readSet.Tables[1].rows) {
   Write-Output "Transactions"
   Write-Output "$($row.free)  "
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid object name 'dbo.UsersParticipations'." 
At C:\Efiester\test2.ps1:18 char:1 
+ $readAdapter.Fill($readSet) |out-null 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid object name 'dbo.UsersParticipations'."
At C:\Efiester\test2.ps1:18 char:1
+ $readAdapter.Fill($readSet) |out-null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: added error message from comment

Answer (score 0):

this bit should be:

```
...
$SQLCommand.CommandText = 
"select count(*) 'Nombre de Address mail' FROM dbo.UsersParticipations; select count(*) 'Nombre de Transactions' FROM dbo.Transactions"
...
```

not sure if that will sort all the errors but it's a start

Comment: are you sure the table UsersParticipations exists and is under the schema dbo? have you tried the query directly on sql server?